# Listviewitem trims content

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I can't seem to solve this (WPF/c#).

I have 2 windows, parent and child.

In the parent window there's a listviewitem with an item.
In the child window there's a textbox to choose the content( a string) of that item and the button "Create" to confirm that the strng in the textbox goes in the listviewitem, after which the child window closed.

picture:[enter link description here](http://yumenofufe.thealleycat.it/er2.png)

BUT, often when I click create the text gets trimmed. I cannot reproduce it, not even using the same name, which is weird.

picture:[enter link description here](http://yumenofufe.thealleycat.it/er3.png)

I'm using a listview because it has to look exactly the same as a listview near that which has many items.

Here's the code from the "create" button.

```html
//Here I put the name into the listview item and into a setting variable for future use.
myparent.lstbcostum.Content = txtname.Text;
Properties.Settings.Default.CostumName = txtname.Text;
                                                       
//other code for saving other stuff
 var savepath = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Beats\\Costum";
FileInfo myFile = new FileInfo(savepath + "A.wav");
myFile.Attributes = FileAttributes.Normal;
File.Copy(Globals_Costum.Beata, savepath + "A.wav", true);
myFile = new FileInfo(savepath + "B.wav");
myFile.Attributes = FileAttributes.Normal;
File.Copy(Globals_Costum.Beatb, savepath + "B.wav", true);

//other code for saving other stuff and saving settings
Properties.Settings.Default.CostumFlag = true;
myparent.lstbcostum.IsEnabled = true;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
                                                             
//Closing child                                              this.Close();                                               WpfApplication1.Window3.Globals_Beat.frmCostumOpened = false;
```

Comment: Can you add some code snippets to your question?

Comment: Hi, I added the "create" button code.

Answer (score 0):

In your WPF XAML template for the listbox/listview you probably have a textblock. Make sure you have the horizontal alignment for that textblock element set to "Stretch", or, try setting the horizontalcontentalignment for the listbox/listview to "Stretch". It looks like whatever it is that's in there has a fixed width.

Was confused at first because from the screenshots it looks like it was replacing the 5 with an exclamation mark..

Comment: I tried, but it was already set to stretch, so I tried other alignment but still sometimes it cuts the text off. I even tried every time after putting the text resetting the width, but nothing.

Comment: Could you post the relevant XAML as well?